# set fragment as empty view for listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

I have a list view and when i don't have any item in my list view I want to show a text and also button, before I just had a text and I used setEmptyView, but since I want to add button I cannot use setEmptyView, I decide to use fragment, I have fragment but how can I add , i mean instead of using setEmptyView using fragment:

Appreciate if you can help me with code:

Here is the code:

```
listView.setEmptyView(getActivity().findViewById(R.id.empty_list));
registerForContextMenu(listView);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest try using a FrameLayout instead...

So in your layout you can have something like

```
<FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/empty_list_textview"
        ...      >
        <TextView
            ... />
       <Button 
            ... />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for comment, Ok , do I need to add it via code also?

Comment: You still need to set the empty view of list in code.